# How to gzip http request post(client) data for node.js server

Tags: node.js, http, gzip

I have implemented node.js server application, which accepts post data from client(long json string). Is there a way I can gzip the post data at browser end and unzip it in node.js?

I specifically want to gzip the request and not response.

Comment: https://stuk.github.io/jszip/

Comment: How will it be decompressed at node.js? Moreover jszip is for zipping files, I want to compress post data (JSON string, not a file)

Comment: nodejs unzip:https://nodejs.org/api/zlib.html

Answer (score 1):

check https://jsfiddle.net/gynz82tg/
decompress in nodejs just same after you get the base64 encoded request string.

```js
var jsonStr = JSON.stringify({
  name: "JiangYD"
})
$('#origin').text(jsonStr);
var zip = new JSZip();
zip.file("data", jsonStr);
var content = zip.generate();
$('#compressed').text(content);

zip = new JSZip(content, {base64:true});
$('#decompressed').text(zip.file("data").asText());
```

```html
<script src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Stuk/jszip/master/dist/jszip.js"></script>
<div id='origin'></div>
<div id='compressed'></div>
<div id='decompressed'></div>
```

**UPDATE**
because jsZip update the API

https://jsfiddle.net/cvuqr6h4/

```js
async function go(){
 const jsonStr = JSON.stringify({
   name: "JiangYD"
 })
 $('#origin').text(jsonStr);
 let zip = new JSZip();
 zip.file("data", jsonStr);
 const content = await zip.generateAsync({type : "base64"});
 $('#compressed').text(content);

 zip = new JSZip();
 await zip.loadAsync(content, {base64:true});
 const decoded = await zip.file("data").async('string');
 $('#decompressed').text(decoded);
}

go();
```

Comment: When trying the JSFiddle - I'm getting 
Cross-Origin Read Blocking (CORB) blocked cross-origin response <URL> with MIME type text/plain. See <URL> for more details.

can you provide a fixed JSFiddle example?
Thanks!

Comment: Thanks!!! I fixed it a little as in your example - nothing is displayed in the decoded div - https://jsfiddle.net/L2royuex/

Comment: yes, base64 should be option to zip async loading. updated.

Answer (score 0):

You could try this: https://github.com/sapienlab/jsonpack

Example Client Code:

```
<script src="jsonpack.js" />
<script>
 var BIG_JSON = {.....};
 var packed = jsonpack.pack(BIG_JSON);
 $.post('path_to_server',packed);
</script>
```

Example Nodejs Code:

```
var jsonpack = require('jsonpack/main');
app.on('/packed_data',function(req,res){
  try{
     jsonpack.unpack(req.data);
  }catch(e){
   //not good packed data. 
 }

})
```

This is a sample code of course i don't know what framework or libraries you use, but you can see how this could be implemented.
Anyway be careful with this because zipping and unzipping data is always a heavy cpu bound task. If you have **several megabytes of data** you dont want to make your users from phones,tablets etc.. to make this tasks!